# Как с Windows попасть на виртуальную машину Linux на которой запущен Docker контейнер?

Tags: linux, docker

Задача простая - найти файл с логами контейнера на хосте. 
Но есть одно "но"...

Docker запущен на машине под управлением Windows, при этом в самом контейнере ОС - Linux. На сколько мне известно, при запуске такого рода контейнеров Docker разворачивает виртуалку с Linux, а на ней уже контейнер. 
Соответсвенно хостом является виртуальная машина под управлением Linux и логи пишутся туда - это предположение,выдвинутое по причине отсутствия других вариантов.

Путь к логам такой - \var\lib\docker\containers\container ID\
container ID-json.log
Собственно вопрос: как попасть в папку var при том, что она находится на ВМ с Linux?

P.S. Я знаю о существовании команды docker logs, но мне нужен именно файл.

Comment: ssh, не? Ну, то есть это стандартный ответ на вопрос "как попасть на линукс-машину".

Comment: Есть идеи откуда можно получить данные для подключения по ssh? Инфа команды docker inspect таких не содержит. Есть какой-то аналог для получения необходимой информаци?

Comment: А при чём тут докер? Я исходил из заголовка вопроса — "попасть на виртуальную машину". У вас ведь есть какая-то виртуальная консоль этой виртуальной машины? `ifconfig`, `ip a ls`...

Comment: Перечитал вопрос ещё раз. А, то есть она какая-то неявная...

Comment: Да, неявная. Docker ее сам создает в процессе запуска контейнера с Linux на винде. И нет понимания каким образом я могу получить данные для подключения к ней.

Answer (score 0):

Залезь внутрь контейнера при помощи

```bsh
winpty docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> sh
```

`winpty` можно взять [здесь](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty). `CONTAINER_ID` можно узнать при помощи команды:

```
docker ps
```

Далее ты можешь лазить внутри своего контейнера и смотреть "вживую" файлы контейнера.

Comment: @user358064 для того, чтобы логи писались на хост нужно при запуске контейнера явно расшарить папку при помощи ключа -v. К примеру `-v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx`. Поэтому тебе тогда будет достаточно просто просмотреть все расшаренные папки. Если же ты конечно уверен в том, что логи пишутся на хост.

Comment: Да, я уверен, что они пишутся на хост. Docker вернул такой путь для записи логов: \var\lib\docker\containers\container ID\ container ID-json.log. Этого пути нет ни в самом контейнере, ни на машине, на которой крутится docker. Насколько мне удалось выяснить, это настройка по дефолту.